# Is there a way to use bgcolor inside a function?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create a plot that takes conditions from a ticker, in this case VIX, and changes the background color on current charts if conditions are met. However, bgcolor keeps throwing this error `line 22: Cannot use 'bgcolor' in local scope.`

Is there a way to keep `bgcolor` in the function so it knows if it should change the background color or not? Thanks!

```
//@version=4

study(title="Help (VIX Momo)", shorttitle="Vix Momo", overlay=false)

stock_1 = input(title='Stock Selection', defval='TVC:VIX')


highlight(stock_1) =>
    
    vix_30sma = security(stock_1, 'D', sma(close, 30)) 
    vix_50sma = security(stock_1, 'D', sma(close, 50)) 
    
    timeFrame_VIX = input(title="Other time frame", type=input.resolution, defval="180")
    
    smaClose_VIX = security(stock_1, timeFrame_VIX, sma(close,200))
    
    threehr_price_VIX = security(stock_1, timeFrame_VIX, close)
    
    red_VIX = (vix_30sma > vix_50sma) and (threehr_price_VIX >= smaClose_VIX) and (close >= vix_50sma)
    
    if red_VIX
        bgcolor(red_VIX ? #eb4034 : na, transp = 80)
    else
        na

p1 = security(stock_1, 'D', highlight(stock_1))

plot(p1, title="VIX")
```

Comment: Do you still need help on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are confused with this condition. But in any case, the final script will look something like this.

```
//@version=4

study(title="Help (VIX Momo) v2", shorttitle="Vix Momo", overlay=false)

stock_1 = input(title='Stock Selection', defval='TVC:VIX')
timeFrame_VIX = input(title="Other time frame", type=input.resolution, defval="180")


highlight() =>
    
    vix_30sma = sma(close, 30)
    vix_50sma = sma(close, 50)
    smaClose_VIX = sma(close,200)
    
    threehr_price_VIX = close
    
    red_VIX = (vix_30sma > vix_50sma) and (threehr_price_VIX >= smaClose_VIX) and (close >= vix_50sma)
    


p1 = security(stock_1, timeFrame_VIX, highlight())

//plot(p1, title="VIX")
bgcolor(p1 ? #eb4034 : na, transp = 80)
```